# C# Updating Azure Dev Ops WorkItem parent using JsonPatchDocument

Tags: json, .net, azure-devops-rest-api, tfs-workitem

I have no problem creating a work item and setting the correct parent value but for the life of me can't work out how to update the parent once it's been created. What I want to do is set the value of the parent link to the url of a different work item.

I though it might have been as sinmple as something like this, where  I sent in an `operation` of `Replace`

```
private JsonPatchOperation GetParentPatchOperation(WorkItem item, Operation operation)
    {
        var patch =
            new JsonPatchOperation()
            {
                Operation = operation,
                Path = "/relations/-",
                Value = new
                {
                    rel = "System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse",
                    url = item.Url,
                    attributes = new { comment = "" }
                }
            };
        return patch;
    }
```

The error that ADO gives is that the type of relation cannot be changed - same error even when the rel that needs to be changed is targeted with the correct index.

I've actually found the solution so see below.

Comment: You need to clarify what "didn't work" means. What *did* happen? An error message? Unexpected results?

Comment: Yeah good point - will edit the question

Comment: Was it really worth a downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this has to be done in 2 operations. First find the index of the `rel` you want to remove

```
var index = workItem.Relations.ToList().FindIndex(r => r.Rel.Contains("<search term>"));
```

Then create 2 `PatchOperations`, one to remove at the index and then one to add a new `rel` pointing to your new workitem.

Comment: Just to clarify (I needed this): remove at index means that in `JsonPatchOperation `you will out `Path = "/relations/" + index` and `Operation` should be `Remove`. After that, a simple `Add` operation would be used.